# matplotlib.pyplot scatter plot only shows a single dot in the graph even with different values

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a movie dataset, I want to scatter plot the mean of computed_sales column and mean of movie_facebook_likes. the mean value for computed_sales is 4097131.5023790644, while for movie_facebook_likes is 7524.472442505948. But the graph shows only a dot.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
plt.scatter(data["compute_sales"].mean(), data["movie_facebook_likes"].mean())
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Mean is one value. You have asked it to plot one value. This is expected behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Scatter plot takes a set of points. All X-coordinates as one array and all Y-coordinates as one array. So you provided only one X-value and its corresponding Y-value. So it is expected that you will only have one point in the plot which is `(x,y) = (4097131.5023790644, 7524.472442505948)`.

So `.mean()` only gives you one value which is why one point. If you wanna plot them all, do this instead:

```
plt.scatter(data["compute_sales"], data["movie_facebook_likes"])
```